# Tail like logging window for my web app?

Tags: html, ajax, logging, phalcon

I am developing an app using Phalcon and would like to create a popup logging window that displays any logging type information when I am logged in (such as DB calls and exceptions).

Alot of my app is driven by Ajax calls. Is it going to be possible to have a window that I can popup on my main app that uses a `tail` like method of displaying this information?

How would I go about this? I'm not entirely sure that what I want is possible with the Ajax calls as they are done in a different request. I can't find anything on the internet as to how I would go about this so any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you didn't said that explicitly, but I imagine that you want this just for development purposes. If so, you can log useful info to a method that checks if it should send that log to the browser based on some criteria (e.g. logged in user is you, the app is in a dev enviroment, etc) and then use Phalcon's FirePHP log adapter to send to log the information to the browser.

You'll just need to have some FirePHP extension in your Firefox or Chrome to be able to see the information under your JavaScript console. And yes, it works well with Ajax calls too.

Let me know if you need further explanations on this...

Comment: OK Thanks. I'll look into that and let you know how I go. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a debug toolkit.. There are lot of toolkit available on [packagist.org](https://packagist.org) and [phalconist.com](http://phalconist.com/). I personally like this [phalcon-debug-widget](https://github.com/jymboche/phalcon-debug-widget) toolkit that you may try.